# Eclipse Project dependencies dont work when exported

Tags: eclipse, maven, frameworks, project

I am currently facing following big problem:

I have a Framework-Project (maven), where a PropertyReader is included (reads "config.properties" in the same package and returns its values):

**This is the Framework-Project:**

[image: Framework-Project]

```
public class PropertyReaderFramework {
    private static Properties props;

    private static void init(){
        String filename = "com/ks/framework/properties/config.properties";
        InputStream input = PropertyReaderFramework.class.getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(filename);
        if (input == null) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " + filename);
            props = null;
        } else {
            props = new Properties();
        }

        try {
            props.load(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String getProperty(String key){
        if(props == null) init();
        return props.getProperty(key);
    }

    public static Properties getProperties(){
        if(props == null) init();
        return props;
    }

}
```

**And my main-project**, where I need the information of the properties-file just has one class (for demonstation):

```
package testmsg;

import com.ks.framework.properties.PropertyReaderFramework;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        try {
            String basepath = PropertyReaderFramework.getProperty("remoteFileAccess.script.location");
            System.out.println(basepath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }

    }
}
```

The funny thing is, that if I execute the main() class in eclipse, it reads the value from the properties correctly.

**But when I export it as a runnable JAR, it throws me following error:**

[image: Errormessage when Exported]

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? I cannot figure out why it behaves like that...

Comment: I figured out that it works when exported, when I prepend "src/" in the filename to be loaded. but again, then it doen't work in eclipse... something is wrong here

Comment: I also found by versioncontrol out that this error exists since I have converted the framework-project into a maven-project. so this might have messed up some paths... any ideas?